# List adapter vs recycle view adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Im looking for the difference in using **list adapter** and **recycleview adapter** in android. Any different about performance, pros and cons in using them.

Comment: https://blog.usejournal.com/why-you-should-be-using-the-new-and-improved-listadapter-in-android-17a2ab7ca644?gi=9a5b1d86c210 
I think this one will solve your question. `ListAdapter` is designed to to solve the animation problem with `DiffUtil`.

Comment: But i can customize more if i use recycle view adapter with DiffUtil so is there a case which we should choose list adapter

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`ListAdapter` is just an extension of `RecyclerView.Adapter` . Its computes diffs between Lists on a background thread with `AsyncListDiff`.

You can obviously  create a `RecyclerView.Adapter` to work in same way . Its just `ListAdapter` already works on this principal out of the box. It defines a contract to force `DiffUtil` uses hence both of its constructor need a `DiffChecker`.

Performance will be same if you use `ListAdapter` or a `RecyclerView.Adapter` with AsyncDiffChecker. Without async Diff checker `ListAdapter's` performance will be better.

Answer (score 29):

`Recyclerview.Adapter`

- best if the list is static

`ListAdapter`

- best if the list is dynamic

Comment: It would be better if you provide the example for both

Comment: For instance: if you update the item of list, if you delete or add items from list ListAdapter is the better option. If you only show data without updating it, Recyclerview.Adapter is the better option.

Answer (score 6):

List Adapter is extension of RecyclerView.Adapter for presenting List data in a RecyclerView, including computing differences between Lists on a background thread.

It usage DiffUtil utility class that calculates the difference between two lists and outputs a list of update operations that converts the first list into the second one.

In recycler view using a LiveData is an easy way to provide data to the adapter, with the help of list adapter it isn't required - you can simply call submitList(List) when new lists are available. You can see implementation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter).

So in a case of static content you can use RecyclerView.Adapter but in case of dynamic content ListAdapter is preferred.